# How to take normal text from database table and change according to defined variable from other database table

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function customer_bill_reminder()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('role') == "ADMIN" || $this->session->userdata('role') == "SUPER ADMIN")
    {

        $from = $this->input->post('from');
        $to   = $this->input->post('to');
    
        $result = $this->MAILModel->customer_sms_reminder($from,$to);
        $result2 = $this->MAILModel->auto_sms_reminder();

        foreach($result2 as $row)
        {
            $message = @$row->sms_template;
        }

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $phone_number = @$row->mobile;
            $year = @$row->bill_period;
            $control_number = @$row->control_number;
            $amount = @$row->bill_amount;
            $message = "You will pay $amount in $year";
           
            echo $message;

            $this->NotificationModel->send_sms($phone_number,$message);
        }
    }
}
```

The above hard coded text from `$message` will change `$amount` and `$year`. I have problem since the text is from the database - when I echo nothing happens, it will output exactly as it is.

I want to get the output as exactly the hard-coded text but it should be from the table.

Comment: Do you mean it will literally echo `You will pay $amount in $year`, without changing $amount and $year into values?

Comment: Yes It will not change $amount and $year but when I put the exactly text from table by declaring in $message it will work great

Comment: I just don't see how that's possible. PHP will parse variable names inside a double-quoted string (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). As far as I know, that feature can't be switched off...but perhaps someone will correct me.

Comment: But...how much debugging have you done? My only observations here are that: first you set `$message` to be the content of `$row->sms_template;`. What does that field contain exactly? And why do you do that, since the second loop would just overwrite it? And secondly, have you tried to individually `var_dump($amount);` and `var_dump($year);` to verify that they contain what you expected?

Comment: The field from table contains "You will pay $amount in $year" . The purpose to put that to make user to be able to edit message. Every person has different $amount to pay. If the message were needed to be hard-coded. It will be no problem

Comment: Yes it would need to be hard-coded (which you have already done in the `$message = "You will pay $amount in $year";` line anyway), because if you load the string from a database field it will not be treated as an interpolated string, and also you're loading it before you've defined the other variables which go into it.

Comment: I have already found solution through using str_replace function

Comment: That's great. If you think it would help others with a similar issue, please add it as an Answer below (see [answer]). Otherwise you can delete the question

Answer (score 1):

```
     $message1    = str_replace('$amount',$amount,$message);

     $message2=str_replace('$phone_number',$phone_number,$message1);
     $message3=str_replace('$control_number',$control_number,$message2);
     $message4=str_replace('$year',$year,$message3);
     $this->NotificationModel->send_sms($phone_number,$message4);
```